# Does the spread syntax creates a false positive typesafe returned object?

Tags: typescript, redux, spread-syntax

I was recently writing a reducer for redux, whereas the payload value of a given action would override its state. An error threw me back to my code when I noticed that my reducer wasn't giving back the object I was expecting and typescript made no complains about it.

```js
interface State {
    value: number;
}

interface Action {
    type: string;
    payload: {
        value: number;
    }
}

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "CORRECT_SHAPE":
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload
            }
        case "INCORRECT_BUT_WARNED":
            return {
                ...state,
                otherprop: "boom!" // will correctly flag incoherent property
            }    
       case "INCORRECT_SHAPE":
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action // will add `type` and `payload` to returned object
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In this simplified version I attempted to show what's happening:

- In the first `case` the returned object is going to be correct and also correctly I don't receive warnings from the compiler.
- In the second `case` the compiler correctly warns me that `otherprop` is not a member of the `Shape` interface.
- The last one was actually where the mistake happened. Spreading the `action` object actually returns an object with additional `payload` and `type` props and does not override the `value`.

I'd like to understand here why typescript doesn't warn me in the third `case` condition that I am building an object that it's not shaped as `State` such as in the second `case`.

Is this a limitation of the spread syntax or am I overlooking something here?

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: It seems like as long as the end object contains a `value` property (to conform to the `State` interface), then *anything* else that is spread is just accepted unquestioningly. Even if manually adding any other property correctly reports an error. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by design. You will find several issues on GH about this (like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13878) or [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14706)). The official reasoning can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12997):

> Reason: freshness checking was to catch issues for things like options bags - this sounds more like a potential case for exact types